# Using a dependency property to create a color from four sliders C#

Tags: c#, binding, slider, dependency-properties

I have an implementation question. I am trying to have a rectangle change color based on the position of four sliders. (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) I am attempting to use a dependency property to combine all four values, convert them to a brush, and apply the brush to a rectangle. First question is, is it possible to do this with one property? If not, do I need a property for each slider and a property that is accessed each time one of the sliders change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer [Creating and using a new Brush or color using sliders and dependency properties in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194668/creating-and-using-a-new-brush-or-color-using-sliders-and-dependency-properties-i/4195006#4195006)

Comment: Thanks! I apologize that I did not see that answer.

Comment: that answer wasn't there when you posted your question. I just remembered your question when i answered the other one.